# How to filter datagridview using text inputted from a rich text box?

Tags: c#-3.0

I have a datagridview that I want to display a data from a database. But I don't want it to display all of the data. I want it to display the data for a specific ID only. Meaning if the user enters 3 ID, it will display the info for that 3 ID. Hence I want to use a rich text box as a filter so that the user can enter multiple ID for each line in the rich text box. The user can enter the ID No. within the rich text box and the data will be used as a filter to display the data for that particular ID. But I cannot make it read beyond the first line of the rich text box. If I enter just one ID in the first line, it works perfectly, but if I enter a second ID in the second line, or in the third line, then it will not display anything at all. I tried using for loop to read each line of the rich text box but it doesn't work. Any advice or solution??
here is my code :

```
namespace TrackCon
{
    public partial class trackInput : Form
    {
        public trackInput()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        }

    /*private void trackInput_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'trackingBMSDATADataSet.BRDATA' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.bRDATATableAdapter.Fill(this.trackingBMSDATADataSet.BRDATA);

    }*/

    private void trackBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RichTextBox dynamicRichTextBox = new RichTextBox(); 
        DataTable dt = null;
        string connoInput = richTextBox1.Text;
        string conString = Properties.Settings.Default.BMSDATAConnectionString;
        //string[] RichTextBoxLines = dynamicRichTextBox.Lines;
        foreach (char line in richTextBox1.Text)
        {
            using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\TrackCon\TrackCon\BMSDATA.sdf;Persist Security Info = True;Password=xxxx"))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT conno,cmpsno,ctrx,dsysdate,cstnno,corigin FROM BRDATA WHERE conno = '" + richTextBox1.Text + "'OR cmpsno = '" + richTextBox1.Text + "'", con);
                SqlCeDataAdapter adap = new SqlCeDataAdapter(com);
                DataSet set = new DataSet();
                adap.Fill(set);
                if (set.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    dt = set.Tables[0];
                }
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                con.Close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a `TextBox` and set `MultiLine` to `true`.

Then you can read all the ids like this:

```
 string[] ids = myTextBox.Text.Split('\n');
```

EDIT:

You can use SQL's IN to find all elements:

```
string sql = "SELECT conno, etc FROM BRDATA WHERE conno IN (" + String.Join(", ", ids) + ")";
```

Comment: do I need to put it in a for loop or if else??because I want to pass the value in the textbox to the filter query.